# Problem with Eclipse svn:ignore

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

I am trying to add a whole package to my svn ignore list.
I thought that putting `*ploo.syntax.analysis*` as pattern would be a match, but it seems as it isn't.

I've also tried without success:

- ****ploo.syntax.analysis****
- ****ploo/syntax/analysis****
- ****ploo\syntax\analysis****

Adding `*` or `analysis` or `*analysis*` will work, though (but that is not exactly what I intend to)

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with Eclipse, but I think it should be applied from the `src` level. Below is the command line equivalent:

svn propset svn:ignore ploo.syntax.analyis .

The command sets the `svn:ignore` property for `src` directory ( current directory in this case ) and the value for the property is `ploo.syntax.analysis`

Answer (score 0):

Devoured, just select the first option man.(Resources by name) in this case. 
I am assuming that you right clicked on the package name >> team >> svn:ignore
Dots (.) are recognized as wildcards.

Comment: The problem is, this is compiler compiler generated code. Later on, I'll have different files with different names generated and this will fail.

Comment: Try "ploo*" without the "" to get the whole ploo directory or just "analysis*" to get just the analysis dir.

Comment: Not that great idea. I have other packages named ploo and I have classes in other packages named analysis. That'll filter them out too.